# Angular2 nested router outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm playing around with Angular 2 and I'm having some troubles with the router.
I want to have a second router-outlet inside the main router-outlet.

Inside the first router-outlet, i redirect to the Home page, where i have the second router-outlet:

```
<router-outlet name="main"></router-outlet>
```

This is my app.routing without the imports.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: 'days', component: DaysComponent, outlet: 'main'}
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

On the HomeComponent ngOnInit I have this

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/(main:days)');
```

But this crashes the web with the following error:

Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find the outlet main to load 'DaysComponent'

How could have the second router-outlet inside the main one?

Thank you.

Comment: Similar to: [auxiliary-router-outlet-inside-primary-router-outlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893428/auxiliary-router-outlet-inside-primary-router-outlet) I have the same issue...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with this route configuration:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},

    {
        path: 'wrap',
        component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'days',
            component: DaysComponent,
            outlet: 'main'
          }
        ]
    }
];
```

and this URL:

```
this.router.navigate(['/wrap', { outlets: { main: 'days' } }]);
```

or (equivalent)

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/wrap/(aux:aux)');
```