# Use auxiliary routes in nested child components

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I'm trying to use [Auxiliary Routes](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/) within a child-component similar to the problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893428/auxiliary-router-outlet-inside-primary-router-outlet). Since the posted "solution" is more like a workaround I'm curious how to do it like in the blogpost above.

I'm using Angular 2.1.2 with Router 3.1.2.

**parent.module**

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule }         from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule }        from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { ParentComponent }      from './parent.component';

import { ChildModule }          from '../child/child.public.module';
import { ChildComponent }       from '../child/child.public.component';

import { OtherModule }          from '../other/other.public.module'


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ChildModule,
        OtherModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', component: ChildComponent }
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [ ParentComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ ParentComponent ]
}) 

export class ParentModule { }
```

**parent.component**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
    })

export class ParentComponent{ }
```

**child.module**

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule}          from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule }         from '@angular/common';

import { ChildComponent }       from './child.public.component';

import { OtherComponent }       from '../other/other.public.component'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        OtherModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {path: 'other', component: OtherComponent, outlet: 'child'}
        ])
    ],
    declarations: [ ChildComponent ],
    exports:    [ ChildComponent ],
})
export class ChildModule { }
```

**child.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({

    selector: 'child-view',
    template: '<router-outlet name="child"></router-outlet>',
})

export class ChildComponent{}
```

So when I try to browse to /(child:other) I get the typical:

**error**

```
Cannot find the outlet child to load 'OtherComponent'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bit of confusion in there.

Let's have a look at the parent route:

- the only route available is path:"" which will load the child.component

For the child route

- this is in the child.module which is not being loaded at all by the parent module.

A few things I'd try first:
- add the named outlet to the parent.component
- add a route to the other component in the parent route

See if it works. Once you get it working....

- load the child.module by doing this in the main route:

  { path: 'child', loadChildren: 'app/child.module#ChildModule' }
- example of the child route:

  { path: 'other', component: OtherComponent, outlet: 'side'}

then you could browse like this:

/child/(side:other)

I've got a working example in here if you want to give it a try:
https://github.com/thiagospassos/Angular2-Routing

Cheers

Comment: As far as I can see it, it's the same solution as I mentioned above in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893428/auxiliary-router-outlet-inside-primary-router-outlet

In fact the route IS loaded by the parent module via the Router Instance (.forChild). Otherwise it would throw an error for a missing route anyways.

The major problem is, that the Router has no idea where to find nested router outlets.

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the router-outlet because it's not being loaded. Try something like this @usche:

`RouterModule.forChild([
    {path: '', component: ChildComponent},
    {path: 'other', component: OtherComponent, outlet: 'child'}
])`

this way the root route of the child will load the ChildComponent where it has the named outlet and the 'other' route will load inside it

Comment: Thats exactly what I tried and as mentioned it throws: Cannot find the outlet child to load 'OtherComponent'.

Comment: Created a plunker so you can see it working. It's got a second level though: https://plnkr.co/edit/pSKqvH4vf3HinrZZjWDZ