# Navigating to nested/multiple auxiliary routes in angular 4

Tags: angular, router, angular-router, angular-auxiliary-routes

I am trying to navigate to a nested auxiliary route, and I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise):
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'sign-in'
```

The URL I am trying to navigate to:

```
http://localhost:4200/(modalcontainer:modals//modalview:sign-in)
```

My router config for the route looks like this:

```
{
  path: 'modals',
  component: ModalsComponent,
  outlet: 'modalcontainer',
  children: [
      {
          path: 'register',
          outlet: 'modalview',
          component: ModalRegisterComponent
      },
      {
          path: 'sign-in',
          outlet: 'modalview',
          component: ModalSigninComponent
      }
  ]
}
```

So there are 2 `router-outlets` which are `modalcontainer` and `modalview`. The latter is inside the template of `ModalsComponent`.

#### AppComponent

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="modalcontainer"></router-outlet>
```

#### ModalsComponent

```
<div class="overlay" (click)="close($event)">
  <router-outlet name="modalview"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The `modalcontainer` populates ok, but as soon as I try to populate the `modalview` outlet, it errors.

Ways of navigating I have tried are:

- `[routerLink]="[{outlets: {'modalcontainer': ['modals'], 'modalview': ['register']}}]"`
- `[routerLink]="[{outlets: {'modalcontainer': ['modals'], 'modalview': ['modals', 'register']}}]"`
- `[routerLink]="['modals', {outlets: {'modalview': ['register']}}]"`
- Directly typing into the address bar `http://localhost:4200/(modals:modals//modal:sign-in)`
- `this.router.navigate([{outlets: {'modalcontainer': ['modals'], 'modalview': ['register']}}]);`
- `this.router.navigateByUrl('/(modals:modals//modal:sign-in)');`

Is it something in my configuration or the way I am accessing the URLs? Or is this a bug?

Comment: today I tested it and say about my result.

Comment: Diplicate this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893428/auxiliary-router-outlet-inside-primary-router-outlet/40932620#40932620

Comment: Seems like you should have tried `http://localhost:4200/(modalcontainer:modals/(modalview:sign-in))`.

Answer (score 1):

I never found an answer to this - it seems like a bug in angular. For anyone who is having the same issue, my solution was to remove the nesting.

I removed the outlet of modalcontainer.

I added modalview directly into my main component instead.

I made the view that was previously injected into modalcontainer a component that accepted content and use it as the base commponent for each of my modalviews.

---

#### AppComponent

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="modalview"></router-outlet>
```

#### ModalsComponent

```
<div class="overlay" (click)="close($event)">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

#### ModalRegisterComponent

```
<modal-container>
  <h3>Register</h3>
  ...
</modal-container>
```

#### Router Config

```
{
    path: 'modals/register',
    outlet: 'modalview',
    component: ModalRegisterComponent
},
{
    path: 'modals/sign-in',
    outlet: 'modalview',
    component: ModalSigninComponent
}
```